# Customizable content inside DataTemplate

Tags: wpf

I have the following data template for a `TemplateGridViewModel`. It renders a paginated grid of items where the pages can be navigable.

I want to be able to use the template with different items. Currently it just displays a label.

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TemplateGridViewModel}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5" Margin="10 20">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPage}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="4" Rows="2"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5">
                        <Label Content="{Binding ManagedTemplateId}"/> 
                        <!-- What I want is: 
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/> 
                         -->
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I imagine that I could display my interchangeable content by replacing the label with `<ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>` (or even just `<ContentPresenter/>`?).

And then it would be used like this:

```xml
<ContentControl Content="{Binding IndexViewModel}">
    <!--Interchangeable content here!-->
</ContentControl>
```

But ah, you see the problem! Content is already defined, it's the view model which is what binds us to this template in the first place!

**How can I present a viewmodel via datatemplate and use interchangeable content?**

Comment: What's the "interchangeable content" in this case? Is it a property of the view model or what?

Comment: It will be defined whenever the control is used, in the xaml as the content of the ContentControl (although indeed my point is that it already has the content set)

Comment: Add the `Border` to a `UserControl` or a custom `ContentControl` and replace the `Label` with a `ContentPresenter`? Then you add the control to the `DataTemplate`. Is this what you want?

Comment: I have seen that answer elsewhere, and it does seem like a good solution. @MarkFeldman's solution below is quicker and simpler (and possibly more MVVM-perfect? I'm definitely interested.) but I would greatly welcome a posted answer in your direction.

Comment: Is the content the same for all pages in the `ItemsControl`?

Comment: Yes. A page is just a subset of the actual items source. (The constructor of the `TemplateGridViewModel` takes `items` and splits them up into `Pages`)

Comment: Why don't you add another `Content` property then?

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: Instead of binding to `Content, you could bind to another content property that you define yourself: `<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyAdditionalContent}"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind an ItemsControl it sets the view model of each visual list item to the corresponding collection item, so replace the label with this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
```

Then add DataTemplates for the types that are in your `CurrentPage` collection.